# Generating of query in wrong format

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a problem with piece of code, which is generated (output) in wrong format and not requested form:

I wanted generate query/sql with foreign key without "ALTER TABLE NameOfTab ADD" so I used this piece of code:

```java
DSL.constraint(DSL.name("fk_example"))
   .foreignKey("id1","id2")
   .references("referecnedTableName", "referencedColumn1", "referencedColumn2");
```

And here comes a problem because it returns as string this form:

```sql
constraint "fk_example"
foreign key (
"id1", 
"id2"
)
references "referecnedTableName" (
"referencedColumn1", 
"referencedColumn2"
)
```

Expected result is:

```sql
constraint fk_example foreign key (id1, id2) 
references referecnedTableName (referencedColumn1, referencedColumn2)
```

Something similar in correct format does ALTER table:

```java
ctx.alterTable(tableName)
   .add(
      DSL.constraint(DSL.name("fk_example"))
         .foreignKey("id1","id2")
         .references("referecnedTableName","referencedColumn1","referencedColumn2"))
   .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED));
```

But it returns it with "alter table t3 add ... " and I don't want "alter table" part.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`DSLContext.render(QueryPart)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#render-org.jooq.QueryPart-) instead of `QueryPart.toString()`. The `toString()` behaviour defaults to calling `render()` with some unspecified default `Settings` including the generation of those double quoted identifiers, which I'm suspecting you don't want to have.

Comment: Thats what I wanted ;) thank you, I already do it by removing alter table part with regex matches :D but this is better :)